# Why can a directory be removed when my shell is using that directory?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, directory

I don't know if what I encountered was a bug or is intended behavior, but luckily I figured out pretty quick what was going on.

I had my shell cd'd inside a subdirectory of the git repo, and I performed a `git rebase -i` squash operation in which the commits involved included the creation of this directory.

After that operation completed without incident, the shell became in an orphaned state where the `git status` (neither in the zsh theme helper RPROMPT nor when run) indicated that I wasn't even in a git repository anymore.

Once I ran `cd ..` everything was fine, and it all made sense. During the course of the rebasing operation, Git had `rm`'d the directory that I was in (at the first step of the rebase) and subsequently put it back. Since it got put back, I could also have ran `cd $(pwd)` to go there in one step.

This is some confusing behavior. Although, it is not clear that anything was technically done wrong by git. My question is would this be a bug in `git` or should users be expected to know how to deal with this situation?

Also, the wider, actual root question: Why is it permitted to remove a directory that my shell is in, when it is not permitted to eject a disk if I have a shell on a mounted directory? It seems inconsistent to me.

Case in point: `fuser <directory>` shows current directory uses. If a program is "on" a directory it is "using" it.

Comment: I have to assume that like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237836/12497) states that the ability to delete something while it is in use is just the way it's supposed to work, and this necessarily creates that tradeoff of potential confusion relating to the program still having access to the deleted thing. (In this case: The shell retaining a handle on the removed directory, as a consequence of git being permitted by the OS to remove that directory)

Answer (score 1):

Terminal 1:

```
$ cd tmp/
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ rmdir tmp/test
```

Terminal 1:

```
$ ls 
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

Inconsistent, yes. But allowed.

PS. And this has nothing to do with `git`.

Comment: Yes. It is very good to point out that this has nothing inherently to do with git; I just think someone will encounter this while working with git and my keywords might help them.

Comment: No need for the second terminal. `mkdir test; cd test; rmdir ../test; pwd` will do it. And I don't agree that it's inconsistent, it's perfectly reasonable that she shell maintains CWD as a "state" without the need to keep an open filehandle on the directory.

Comment: It's inconsistent with not allowing unmounting a filesystem when there is process that did `cd` into the FS.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

It is not a bug, it is how Unix systems, including Linux, have always worked.

There's even some nice text in the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html):

> [EBUSY] The directory to be removed is currently in use by the system or some process and the implementation considers this to be an error.

Namely, some implementation (e.g. Windows...) can call it an error, but most implementations. namely Unix variants, do not.

The way this is implemented in a filesystem is by having the processes hold a reference on the object which represents the directory. Another thing that holds such a reference is the parent directory. `git rebase` has removed the latter reference, but the former remains. Even if the directory is re-created, it is a new filesystem object, whereas your shell was holding a reference to the old object.

That's why `cd ..` and `cd $(pwd)` still work - they re-lookup the directory and grab the new reference, and release the old reference.

Officially the old object is not cleaned up until the old reference is released. That means that the metadata of the directory is not removed from the disk until the process releases the old working directory.

To answer your second question:

In order to eject a drive you have to unmount the mountpoint, and as above, the processes you find with `fuser` hold references to that mountpoint.

As with directory references, a amount point cannot be cleaned up until all references to it have been removed. That is why you cannot eject a drive which has references.

The consistent thing to do would be to allow detaching the filesystem from the directory tree without actually cleaning up. You still won't be able to eject the drive, but at least you can use the directory tree as you wish.

Well, that is actually possible to do with `umount --lazy`.